# PHP How to check if a String is contained in a text from the database using php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

I'm creating a paraphrasing system, where a user inputs text and the system paraphrases for them.

My database looks like this:

KeyWord: dainty

Synonyms1: choice; delicious; tasty; juicy; luscious; palatable; savoury

Synonyms2:  ethereal; beautiful; fragile; charming; petite; frail; elegant

where Keyword (varchar), Synonym1 (text), and Synomy2 (text) are database columns. The example above is one row of a database with 3 fields and their values.

This how it works if the system finds, for example, a word like **tasty**, it can be replaced by any of the words separated by a semicolon from either Synomyn1 or Synonym2 or the keyword because they are all synonyms.

Let me explain how the word search is working. The system first searches for the word in the Keyword column, if the word is not found, I go further and search for a word in the Synmon1 column and so on.

My Problem is checking the user's specific word in the Synonym1 or Synonym2 columns. When I use the LIKE clause, the generic way of searching from the database, the system is not searching for a full name, instead, it's searching for characters. For example, let's assume the writer's text is: "**Benson has an ice cube**", the system is assuming the ice was found in the cho**ice**. I don't want that, I want to search for a full word.

If anyone has understood me, please help to solve this.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Please check the last paragraph, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to search for `ice` in columns `Synonyms1` and `Synonyms2` but make sure you do not inadvertently match a word such as `choice`.

If you have ever read or heard anything on the subject of database normalization you would realize that your database does not even meet the requirements for **1NF** (first normal form) becuase it has columns that consist of repeating values, which, as you have found out, makes searching inefficient and difficult. But let's move on:

A synonym column might just contain one word, so it might look like:

```
ethereal
```

Or:

```
ethereal; beautiful; fragile; charming; petite; frail; elegant
```

Thus the word you are looking for might be:

1. the entire column value
2. preceded by nothing and followed by a `;`
3. preceded by a space and followed by a `;`
4. preceded by a space and followed by nothing

So if your version of MySQL does not support regular expressions, then if you are looking for example the word `ice` in column `Synonyms2`, the WHERE clause should be:

```
WHERE (
   Synonyms2 = 'ice'
   OR
   Synonyms2 like 'ice;%'
   OR
   Synonyms2 like '% ice;%'
   OR
   Synonyms2 like '% ice'
)
```

If you are running SQL 8+, then:

```
WHERE regexp_like(Synonyms2, '( |^)ice(;|$)')
```

This states that `ice` must be preceded by either a space or start of string and followd by either a `;` or end of string.

Comment: I have taken a long time to reply because I was busy applying for this solution. First, I feel great for understanding my question as it was supposed to be. My question is, if I have a word like "dispose of", then `% ice` will be wrong, because "dispose of" ends with "of" and "of" is a word by itself.  If the user enters "of" the system is confusing it with word like "dispose of". Any help with this?

Comment: Out of your solution, I have developed a nice pattern that works fine for my system. Thanks

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding your question. `dispose of` is *two* words. My answer describes how to look up a *single* word, which I thought your synonym columns are composed of based on your examples.After now seeing your second comment, is everything okay?

Comment: If you normalized your tables, so that, for example, you had a table `keyword_synonym1` with columns `keyword` and `synonym` with rows `('smart', 'intelligent'), ('smart', 'sharp'), ('smart', 'quick'), etc.` expressing the synonyms for "intelligent", all of your difficulties go away.